# CakePHP 3.0 : How to make multiple MySQL OR Condition in Query builder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'm using cakePHP 3.0 for REST API. This is MySQL Query.

```
SELECT group_chat.message_parents
FROM group_chat    
WHERE group_chat.sender_groups = 1 AND group_chat.`status` = 1 AND group_chat.is_blocked = 0
OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1 AND group_chat.`status` = 1 AND group_chat.is_blocked = 0
OR group_chat.sender_groups = 1 AND group_chat.`status` = 1 AND group_chat.is_blocked = 1 AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1
OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1 AND group_chat.`status` = 1 AND group_chat.is_blocked = 1 AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1
GROUP BY group_chat.message_parents
ORDER BY group_chat.modified DESC;
```

I converted it in to CakePHP 3.0 Query builder function.

```
$all_parents = $this->GroupChat->find()->select(['message_parents',])
            ->where(['sender_groups' => $params['group_id'], 'status' => ACTIVE, 'is_blocked' => DEACTIVE, 'blocked_by' => DEACTIVE])
            ->orWhere(['recever_groups' => $params['group_id'], 'status' => ACTIVE, 'is_blocked' => DEACTIVE, 'blocked_by' => DEACTIVE])
            ->orWhere(['sender_groups' => $params['group_id'], 'status' => ACTIVE, 'blocked_by' => $params['group_id']])
            ->orWhere(['recever_groups' => $params['group_id'], 'status' => ACTIVE, 'blocked_by' => $params['group_id']])
            ->order(['modified' => 'DESC'])
            ->group('message_parents');
```

But it is not producin expected results as Query before. Any help will highly appreciated.

**Update:**

```
debug($all_parents);
```

Debug will output this.

```
'sql' => '
SELECT GroupChat.message_parents AS `GroupChat__message_parents` 
FROM group_chat GroupChat 
WHERE ((recever_groups = :c0 AND status = :c1 AND is_blocked = :c2 AND blocked_by = :c3) 
  OR (sender_groups = :c4 AND status = :c5 AND is_blocked = :c6 AND blocked_by = :c7) 
  OR sender_groups = :c8 
  OR status = :c9 
  OR blocked_by = :c10 
  OR recever_groups = :c11 
  OR status = :c12 OR blocked_by = :c13) 
GROUP BY message_parents  
ORDER BY modified DESC',
```

Comment: What is the query that gets created? Can you debug and post the query?

Comment: Amo How can I do it?

Comment: just do debug($all_parents); and you will get the query

Comment: If you switch on debugging, there should be a little cake icon on the bottom right of your browser. Clicking it will show debugging information. Try that?

Comment: @Mayura you should read this http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions

Comment: @Arno Yes I have already switched on debugging but since I'm developing a REST API application I can't see any icon.

Comment: @justrohu yes I read that book, but it is not helping for my task.

Comment: What's the problem with the results? Is it which rows are returned, the order or both?

Answer (score 0):

Your raw SQL query hasn't got any grouping. So it effectively translates to each condition being `OR`ed or `AND`ed:

```
WHERE group_chat.sender_groups = 1 
    AND group_chat.`status` = 1
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 0
    OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1
    AND group_chat.`status` = 1
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 0
    OR group_chat.sender_groups = 1
    AND group_chat.`status` = 1
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 1
    AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1
    OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1
    AND group_chat.`status` = 1
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 1
    AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1
```

Since `A AND A = A` and `A OR A = A` (basic boolean algebra) the above is reduced to:

```
WHERE group_chat.sender_groups = 1
    OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1
    AND group_chat.`status` = 1
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 0
    AND group_chat.is_blocked = 1
    AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1
```

Which is most probably not what you intended.

The CakePHP query you wrote is *grouping* the `AND`s and `OR`s and that explains why it produces different results.

Comment: Actually It should be some thing like this  SELECT group_chat.message_parents
FROM group_chat
WHERE group_chat.`status` = 1 
AND ( ( group_chat.sender_groups = 1 OR group_chat.recever_groups = 1 )
AND  group_chat.is_blocked = 0 OR (group_chat.is_blocked = 1 AND group_chat.blocked_by = 1))
GROUP BY group_chat.message_parents
ORDER BY group_chat.modified DESC;

Comment: Ok, so now you know what you want to do, go on and fix it :) I'm glad this answer helped!